# Procurar informação pelo conteúdo e não pela posição do array

Tags: array, asp

Quero fazer uma busca de determinada palavra de uma outra forma, eu apenas consegui dessa descrita abaixo:

```
<%
mystring = "Como eu faço para separar uma string em várias strings?"
myarray = Split(mystring, " ")
For i = 0 to Ubound(myarray)
  Response.Write i & " - " & myarray(i) & "<br>"
  if myarray(0) = "Como" then
    existe = "Sim"
  Else
    existe = "Nao"
  end if
Next
Response.Write "Resposta Final >" & existe
%>

0 - Como
1 - eu
2 - faço
3 - para
4 - separar
5 - uma
6 - string
7 - em
8 - várias
9 - strings?
```

Resposta Final >Sim

Eu quero procurar em toda *string* que transformei em array, procurando não por posição `myarray(0)` zero, por exemplo, mas sim por `myarray(i)`, porém o resultado vem "Não", eu preciso usar essa estrutura num outro projeto que usa CheckBox's e nunca saberei qual posição virá. É possível alterar para a forma `myarray(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Seu resultado vem "Não" porque na passada seguinte a resposta é não. Assim que encontrar o resultado, você precisa sair do loop:

```
<%
mystring = "Como eu faço para separar uma string em várias strings?"
myarray = Split(mystring, " ")
For i = 0 to Ubound(myarray)
  Response.Write i & " - " & myarray(i) & "<br>"
  if myarray(i) = "Como" then
    existe = "Sim"
    Exit For
  Else
    existe = "Nao"
  end if
Next
Response.Write "Resposta Final >" & existe
%>
```

<sub>***Atenção: código não testado :)***</sub>

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar a função split. Segue o exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<%

myString=Split("Como eu faço para separar uma string em várias strings?")
for each x in myString
   response.write(x & "<br>")
next

%>  

</body>
</html>
```

Para maiores dúvidas http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa realmente transformar em array?
Se não precisar pode usar expressão regular, é muito mais eficaz. Abaixo segue exemplo em php, é só converter para asp.

```
$str = "Como eu faço para separar uma string em várias strings?";
$ret = preg_match("/eu/", $str);
//$ret retorna true no caso acima
```